# Ambiguous Password in Mimikatz result?

Tags: windows, passwords, kerberos

I executed Mimikatz on my windows server and got the following result for kerberos, why **Password** is in this ambiguous format??

```
kerberos : 
* Username : USR080$
* Domain     : domain.com
* Password : RHzZ^]nr8@6gpN*spD0;57Ory>PEf$R?,=\-ahI]I@su[h(t$M:h<w_a"W[DNNT<Af?lrD;? 
  FSpS(#2=HGoG"eR"9]/^BuU-#GYM#nh4BQ\at*>Aap^3W5PN
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

1. it's a hacking tool that doesn't understand the internals of the system it's inspecting so it's making a best-guess attempt at what it thinks is a password.
2. What makes you think that isn't the password?

Comment: Because I already know the password, beside in some cases it just show some long hex values as password that is different from what we have here.